# solve $e^x = x^{100}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can't solve 
$$e^x = x^{100}$$
for $x$ to find where they intersect.

Setting them equal to each other and taking the $\ln$ of both sides gives $x = 100 \ln x$. And I'm stuck.  What am I missing?

Comment: In general there is no closed form; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function for one way to express the solution.

Comment: What you are missing is that this equation does not have a nice clean solution you can find with a formula. You can find a numerical approximation, or use the Lambert W function .

Comment: Worth noting:  it's not difficult to count the solutions.  Just looking at the two graphs, convince yourself that there are two positive solutions and one negative solution.  (moreover, one solution is near $1$, the other near $-1$.  The third isn't so easy to locate).

Comment: Looking at [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yznaihoi0w), the solutions are $(-0.99, 0.3715)$, $(1.0102, 2.746)$. One should not expect any others since $x^{100}\gg e^x$.

Comment: @Crosby:  as $x$ gets large $e^x \gt x^{100}$.  It just takes a while.

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, I see. Since $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{100}}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{100x^{99}}{e^x}=\cdots =\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0$$.

Comment: @Crosby   Monster math:  take $x=10^3$.  Then $x^{100}=10^{300}$.  But $\log_{10} e^x=10^3 \times \log_{10} e\approx 434$ so the third solution is $<10^3$.  In reality it is about $647.278$.

Comment: take logs both sides, log strictly increasing function, 100 log x > x becomes false at large x, for example $10^{100}$ its easy to see it's false

Answer (score 1):

You can get [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%3Dx%5E100) in terms of the Lambert W function, giving $$x = -100 W(-1/100)\\x = -100 W(1/100)\\x = -100 W_{(-1)}(-1/100)$$
or get numeric answers
$$x \approx 1.01015,-0.990147,647.278$$
One dimension root finding will find these.  It is discussed in any numerical analysis text.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x = 100 \ln x$, which can be written $\frac{\ln x}{x} = 0.01$

Since this question is marked "precalculus", you will have to rely on qualitative arguments to see that  $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ will be postive for $x>0$, and tend monotonically towards zero for $x\to \infty$. Since  $\frac{\ln x}{x} =0$ at $x=1$, it's fairly clear that there is a peak value, which in fact occurs at $x=e$.

[image]

Thus the line $0.01$ will cut this curve twice in positive values. Numerical evaluation puts the two results near $x=1.01$ and $x=647$.

Since the exponent on $x$ is even, there is also a solution for negative $x$. This can be found similarly by considering $w=-x$ and  $e^{-w} = w^{100}$ and then looking for the point where the above curve cuts $-0.01,$ which is close to $w=0.99$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first suppose $x>0$. Then we can transform the equation into
$$
x=100\log x
$$
and we can consider the function $f(x)=x-100\log x$. Clearly
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
and we have
$$
f'(x)=1-100/x
$$
which only vanishes at $x=100$. Therefore we know that $x=100$ is a point of minimum for $f$. Now
$$
f(100)=100-100\log 100<0
$$
so we conclude that the equation $f(x)=0$ has two solutions.

If $x<0$, we can set $x=-y$ and the equation becomes $-y=100\log y$. If we consider $g(y)=y+100\log y$ we see that $g'(y)=1+100/y>0$, so the function is increasing. Since
$$
\lim_{y\to0}g(y)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{y\to\infty}g(y)=\infty
$$
we conclude that the equation $g(y)=0$ has a single solution.

In total, the equation $e^x=x^{100}$ has three solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  [Kantorovich's  theorem on Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem)
method in its classical formulation. Set the function $F:(-\infty,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
F(x)=e^x-x^{100}.
$$
In the absence of a method of finite steps to solve an equation $F(x)=0$ there is a powerful method of resolution by interaction. The Kantorovich's  theorem on Newton's interactions. The method  sometimes (very rarely) results in a finite step method and thus exact solution.

> Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a interval
>     and $F:{I}\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, continuously
>     differentiable on $\mathrm{int}(I)$. Take $x_0\in \mathrm{int}(I)$,
>     $L,\, b>0$ and suppose that
>
> - $F '(x_0)$ is non-singular,
> - $ \|  F'(y)-F'(x)
>       \| \leq L\|x-y\|
>       \;\;$  for any $x,y\in I$,
> - $ \|F'(x_0)^{-1}\cdot F(x_0)\|\leq b$,
> - $2\cdot b\cdot L\leq 1$.
>
> Define
>     $
>     t_*:=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2bL}}{L}. 
>   $
>     If 
>     $
>   [x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]\subset I,
>   $
>     then  the sequences $\{x_k\}$ generated by Newton's Method for
>     solving $F(x)=0$ with starting point $x_0$,
>   $$
>     x_{k+1} ={x_k}-F'(x_k) ^{-1}F(x_k), \qquad k=0,1,\cdots, 
>  $$
>     is well defined, is contained in $(x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*)$, converges to a
>     point $x_*\in [x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]$ which is the unique zero of $F$ in
>     $[x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]$.

Here a expository Article: [Kantorovich's s theorem on  Newton's method.](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_KantNewt_2012_1209.5704v1.pdf?1351508016). See too other expository Article [here.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316909?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents). See Ortega's paper [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2313800.pdf) for a simple proof.