# Find the range of initial values for which Newton–Raphson's method for $f(x) = a - \frac{1}{x}$ converges

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, newton-raphson

I'm tryig to use Newton–Raphson's method to compute the inverse of $a$. Given $f(x) = a - \frac{1}{x}, a \neq 0$ we are looking for $x^*$ such that $f(x^*) = 0$. Newton–Raphson's  method gives the sequence $x_{n+1} = -ax_n^2 + 2x_n$. For example let $a = 2$, so $x_{n+1} = -2x_n^2 + 2x_n$. So want to find for which initial values $x_0$ the method converges. Playing around with an algorithm I implemented I found that $x_0$ must be in $(0, 1)$ for it to converge.

But how can I prove that? And in the more general case of $a$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See related question in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2824981/19266

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numerical Methods: calculate $b/a$ without division](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186607/numerical-methods-calculate-b-a-without-division)

Comment: More specifically, the approach taken in the accepted answer is exactly what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Kantorovich's theorem for Newton's method?

> **Theorem of  Kantorovich.** Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a interval 
>     and $F:{I}\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, continuously
>     differentiable on $\mathrm{int}(I)$. Take $x_0\in \mathrm{int}(I)$,
>     $L,\, b>0$ and suppose that
>
> - $F '(x_0)$ is non-singular,
> - $ \|  F'(y)- F'(x)
>       \| \leq L\|x-y\|
>       \;\;$  for any $x,y\in I$,
> - $ \|F'(x_0)^{-1}\cdot F(x_0)\|\leq b$,
> - $2\cdot b\cdot L\leq 1$.
>
> Define
>     $
>     t_*:=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2bL}}{L}. 
>   $
>     If 
>     $
>   [x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]\subset I,
>   $
>     then  the sequences $\{x_k\}$ generated by Newton's Method for
>     solving $F(x)=0$ with starting point $x_0$,
>     $$
>     x_{k+1} ={x_k}-F'(x_k) ^{-1}F(x_k), \qquad k=0,1,\cdots, 
>   $$
>     is well defined, is contained in $(x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*)$, converges to a
>     point $x_*\in [x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]$ which is the unique zero of $F$ in
>     $[x_0-t_*,x_0+t_*]$.

Here a expository Article: [Kantorovich's s theorem on  Newton's method.](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_KantNewt_2012_1209.5704v1.pdf?1351508016). See too other expository Article [here.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316909?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents). See Ortega's paper [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2313800.pdf) for a simple proof.

See [personal home page of  Prof. Ferreira](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/p/3371-publications) for articles of Newton-Kantorovich method and variants in Banach spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What i posted was a homework problem from a course I am taking and we haven't been told about Kantorovich's theorem. I bet it would be interesting to read through it but what I posted can be solved using another approach and that's what I would be more interested in at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

A coarse appreciation.

The Newton-Raphson recurrence formula is $x_{k+1} = \phi(x_k)$ then

$$
x_{k+1}-x_k = \phi(x_k)-\phi(k_{k-1})=\phi'(\zeta)(x_k-x_{k-1}),\ \ \zeta\in B(x_k,x_{k-1})
$$

For convergence it is sufficient then that $|\phi'(\zeta)| < 1$ for $\zeta\in B(x_k,x_{k-1})$

Here $B(x_k,x_{k-1})$ is an open neighbourn containing $(x_k,x_{k-1})$.

In our case $\phi(x) = -ax^2+2x$ and $\phi'(x) = -2ax+2$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have checked that $|\phi '(\zeta)| < 1$ for $\zeta \in (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})$ but I want to find the interval in which $x_0$ must be for it to converge and I observed that it was $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @DaMike: Among other things, your observation is derived in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3186823/307944)

Comment: Sorry for the quite late answer. Reading again the post you linked, I have absolutely no idea what is going on in your answer, starting from the point where you write _"Convergence is assured provided we choose $x_0$ such that $|r_0|^2<1$."_